# Replacing values with ffill in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have various columns in a pandas dataframe that have dummy values and I want to fill them as follows:
Input Columns

```
+----+-----
| c1 | c2 |
+----+----+
|  0 | 1  |
|  0 | 0  |
|  1 | 0  |
|  0 | 0  |
|  0 | 1  |
|  0 | 1  |
|  1 | 0  |
|  0 | 1  |
```

Output columns:

```
+----+-----
| c1 | c2 |
+----+----+
|  0 | 1  |
|  0 | 1  |
|  1 | 1  |
|  1 | 1  |
|  1 | 2  |
|  1 | 3  |
|  2 | 3  |
|  2 | 4  |
```

How can I get this output in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here working if there are only `0` and `1` values cumulative sum - [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df1 = df.cumsum()
print (df1)
   c1  c2
0   0   1
1   0   1
2   1   1
3   1   1
4   1   2
5   1   3
6   2   3
7   2   4
```

If there are `0` and another values is possible use cumulative sum for mask for test not equal `0` values:

```
df2 = df.ne(0).cumsum()
```